# After entering data, it remains in input field ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Novice in React here.

**Check EDIT1 for latest update**

I have a input field and when I write some data in it and then click the button to insert it the data remains in input field.

Here is screenshot after I click `Set` button.

[image]

As you can see the data in both fields remains, but I wish it disappear after I click the button.

As well with that after I click second time `Set` button I receive double of `undefined`.

[image]

Goal: Store the data after clicking Button in a column type. That I can enter multiple time data.

**CODE HERE**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button} from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {   

  const [name, setName] = useState(null);

  let tmpName;
  let tmpPrice;

  const onChangeSymbol = e => {
    tmpName = e.target.value;
  }

  const onChangePrice = e => {
    tmpPrice = e.target.value;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
        {name}
    <input type="text" placeholder="Symbol" onChange={onChangeSymbol}/>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Price" onChange={onChangePrice}/>
    <button onClick={() => setName(tmpName + ' ' + tmpPrice)}>Set</button>
  </div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT1**

After adding @macborowy answer, I face the problem that every time when I enter query I receive it double, check screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {   
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");

  const onChangeSymbol = e => setSymbol(e.target.value);
  const onChangePrice = e => setPrice(e.target.value);

  const onClick = () => {
    if (symbol !== "" && price !== "") {
      setName(symbol+ ' ' + price);
      setSymbol("");
      setPrice("");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
      {name}
      <input type="text" placeholder="Symbol" value={symbol} onChange={onChangeSymbol}/>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Price" value={price} onChange={onChangePrice}/>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Set</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

Update:

> the last thing to ask, is it possible to store more that 1 query? Cause when I write the second query in both input fields and press Set button, appears the new query and old one is deleted. How can I store multiple queries?

Sure, instead of storing last query in the state, you need to push it to an array of queries. Then render contents of this array using `map()`.

Here, I use a second form of `setQueries()` that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument.

Here is an example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {   
  const [queries, setQueries] = useState([]);
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");

  const onChangeSymbol = e => setSymbol(e.target.value);
  const onChangePrice = e => setPrice(e.target.value);

  const onClick = () => {
    if (symbol !== "" && price !== "") {
      setQueries((queries) => {
        queries.push(`${symbol} ${price}`);
        return queries;
      });
      setSymbol("");
      setPrice("");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
      <ul>
        {queries.map(query => <li>{query}</li>)}
      </ul>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Symbol" value={symbol} onChange={onChangeSymbol}/>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Price" value={price} onChange={onChangePrice}/>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Set</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's working but data remains in input fields, after clicking second time on Set button nothing happens. (two undefined doesn't appear as well)

Comment: Check the updated example, I hope it works as expected now.

Comment: Just tested your code, after I click on my dropdown, whole app breaks with this error - Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Event': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Comment: Did you change `const { useState } = React;` to `import React, { useState } from 'react';`? Use this sandbox as a reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-river-e42j7.

Comment: now it's working for me! Thanks man, super appreciated! Upvoted and confirmed

Comment: the last thing to ask, is it possible to store more that 1 query? Cause when I write the second query in both input fields and press Set button, appears the new query and old one is deleted. How can I store multiple queries?

Comment: thanks for answer! It works the only thing that after I enter the result - I receive 2 queries.
For example I write - ADABTC in one field and 50 in another > I receive ADABTC 50 two times

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
  import { Button} from "react-bootstrap";
  
  export default function App() {   
  
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);
    const [price, setPrice] = useState();
  
    let tmpName;
    let tmpPrice;
  
    const onChangeSymbol = e => {
      setName(e.target.value);
    }
  
    const onChangePrice = e => {
      setPrice(e.target.value);
    }
  
    const handleSubmit = () => {
      console.log(name, price);
      setName();
      setPrice();
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
          {name}
      <input value={name} type="text" placeholder="Symbol" onChange={onChangeSymbol}/>
      <input value={price} type="number" placeholder="Price" onChange={onChangePrice}/>
      <button onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>Set</button>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

First of all, do not use "tmp" variables. That is what `useState()` is for. If you go with what I've posted, on every change of the inputs (on every keypress) the value will be saved to `name` and `price`. Once you hit submit, you can use the data however you want (print it to the console, call an API with it...) and then reset the `name` and `price`. The values in the inputs will be erased as well because we added `value={name}` and `value={price}` to them so in a way they are "linked".

Comment: Thanks for answer! Just tested your code. When I enter data in first field it immediately appears in {name} field and Set button doesn't even work. Also in Price field there is 0 which I don't need.

Comment: Hey. I made some fixes. You can give it a go now. The value in `useState(/*here*/)` controls what the starting value will be.

Comment: 0 disappears but the problem is same. I immediately writing in {name} field and when I click "Set' button the {name} disappears

Comment: Well in `handleSubmit` you can use `name` however you want and then it disappears after `setName();`. There you set it to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening in your case:

- First of all, you are using local variables instead of state. So when you call `setName` your component is *rerendered* and variables are cleared. That's what you see when you click on button -> it sets state, the component is rerendered and your variables are declared with default values again.
- You mix **controlled** and **uncontrolled** components concepts: you do not pass `value` to your inputs.

In React such elements as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` can be either controlled or uncontrolled components.

#### Controlled

Controlled means, that you provide `value` for them and control what you display. In that case, you need to use some state, to store current value: in your case you use hook `useState`, so React controls what is displayed in those components and on callbacks you can get changes and then update your stored variable.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  // could be replace with useReducer
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const [tmpName, setTempName] = useState("");
  const [tmpPrice, setTempPrice] = useState("");

  const onChangeSymbol = useCallback(e => setTempName(e.target.value), []);
  const onChangePrice = useCallback(e => setTempPrice(e.target.value), []);

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    setName(`${tmpName} ${tmpPrice}`);
    setTempName("");
    setTempPrice("");
  }, [tmpName, tmpPrice]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
      {name}
      <input type="text" value={tmpName} placeholder="Symbol" onChange={onChangeSymbol} />
      <input type="number" value={tmpPrice} placeholder="Price" onChange={onChangePrice} />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Set</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Uncontrolled

Uncontrolled is a bit different thing: you do not need to provide values and control component and can instead pass ref, with which you can access values of DOM node

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const nameInput = useRef();
  const numberInput = useRef();

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    setName(`${nameInput.current.value} ${numberInput.current.value}`);
    nameInput.current.value = "";
    numberInput.current.value = "";
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
      {name}
      <input type="text" placeholder="Symbol" ref={nameInput} />
      <input type="number" placeholder="Price" ref={numberInput} />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Set</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

More info on https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html